# Replacing names of a file

Tags: python

I have the file and I want to replace names according to the pair of objects in the list and elements inside:

```
def replace_variables(i, distance = 0, T1 ='0', T2 = '0', Phi = '0' ):

        i_[0][0] = '-2'
        i_[1][0] = '2'

       input_name = input_name.replace('distance',distance).replace('one',T1).replace('two',T2).replace('Phi',Phi)
       print input_name


input_name = 'file_distance_one_two_Phi.txt'

a = [['distance','+2','-2'], ['T1','+2','-2'], ['T2','+2','-2'], ['Phi','+2','-2']]

new_list = list(itertools.permutations(a, 2))

for i in new_list:
replace_variables(i, x, y)
```

But I'm getting back:

```
file_distance_T1_0_0.txt, file_-2_T2_0_0.txt, file_distance_-2_0_0_0.txt, and so on
```

I want to get:

```
file_-2,-2_0_0.txt, file_-2_0_-1_0.txt, file_2_-2_0_0.txt and so forth
```

Comment: you're updating a copy. Work directly on the `i` variable instead.

Comment: I updated my code. It sill not what I want

Comment: sorry but now k should be undefined. And indentation is incorrect. Please fix it. If the example is fully runnable, you'll get a million answers :)

Comment: I already corrected it :)

Comment: still not runnable example,  what is x and y?

Comment: Indentation is not correct. See inside `for` loop. And where is x and y assigned? Help us help you. Try copying/pasting this code example to check if it reproduces your issue.